# Share procedure for different units

Tags: delphi, unit-testing

I have 4 `units` in my Delphi project (4 forms too) and I have a procedure in `Unit 2` that is called "controlla".

```
procedure TForm2.controlla(numero:TEdit);
var a:string;
begin
 // the code
end;
```

I made this procedure because it converts a decimal number to a fractional number. By the way, I have to use this function in `Unit 4` too.

I thought I could do a *.dll library with this function. Before trying the libraby way, is there any method that allows me to use `controlla(numero:TEdit)`, that is in unit 2, in Unit 4 without a dll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a fifth unit and put your common methods in there.  MiscUtils.pas, for example.  Then use that unit anywhere you need to call any of the methods.

As an aside, instead of passing in a TEdit, use a string parameter.  That way this method doesn't have to know anything about TEdits, arguably making it more flexible.

Comment: So you mean I could create `Unit5`, put there the function and put `uses Unit5` in other forms?

Comment: Exactly right.  Consider using more meaningful unit names, though.

Comment: Yes, it was just as example ;) +1 and accept because your idea is good and it works

Comment: What are you doing inside this procedure?  If it does something directly to the form, then you might need to make an adjustment.